# Optional return type annotations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

I have a function that will either return a generator (`types.GeneratorType`) or `list`, depending upon the value of an argument. For example:

```
def foo(switch: bool) -> list: # return type of list || types.GeneratorType
    ... # create some generator object named f1
    if switch:
        return list(f1)
    else:
        return f1
```

How do I tell it that I can optionally return a list or another type? Or, for that matter, what about a bunch of different types?

I've looked over [documentation on a module `typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) but haven't as of yet found any methods there that allow for this. I haven't been able to find any examples by Googling either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two solutions that immediately spring to mind are:

1. Make a [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) type

   ```
   def foo(switch: bool) -> Union[list, GeneratorType]:
   ```

   which means *"returns either list or generator"* (you could also use [`Generator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) and [`List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List)); or
2. Type based on the behaviour you can expect from *either* return value, e.g. that they are [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable):

   ```
   def foo(switch: bool) -> Iterable:
   ```

In both cases you could also provide more detail: list or generator/iterable *of what?*

That said, something that returns either a list or a generator sounds like an odd interface, and it would be helpful to provide a bit more context around what consumers of your function should expect to do with whatever they receive. It may be that:

- a single function with two different returns isn't the right interface design; or
- rather than `list` you could use the more general [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence), to permit e.g. `tuple`s to be used instead.

Comment: @bjd2385 it works, but if you gave more information you might get a far better solution to the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: It will be a generator or list full of strings that are filenames with absolute paths, my apologies.

Comment: @bjd2385 but why a generator *or* list? Will things just iterate over whatever they get back (in which case `Iterable[str]` seems appropriate) or what? How will this be *used?*

Comment: Now that you mention it, I don't know and will remove it. I ran with the thought/question though because I knew it may come up with other types, so perhaps this is a poor example.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, here's a concrete example: a function like that above which opens images and returns image data. On the one hand, if I have enough memory, just open them all and `return` a `list` of image (NumPy) arrays. On the other, `yield` each one by one; in each case I have an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to pass "type" as an argument?

```
def foo(switch: type) -> list | tuple | gen_func
    ... # create some generator object named f1
    return switch(f1)

 foo(list) > list type
 foo(tuple) > tuple
 # And if you would want to get generator you would only need to provide
 gen = lambda func_result: (el for el in func_result)
 foo(gen)
```

Dont know if this is the case.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the OP's question, which is how to annotate the return type. Also that's not the correct syntax, or correct annotation for *"returns the same type as the parameter type"*.